# unpack list in pandas dataframe python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe having column a,b,c. And column c has data in list datatype. So I want to unwind/unpacked/explode the each element of list as new row.

so, our input is like below.

```
   a  b             c
0  1  2          [1, {'k': 1}, 2]
1  3  2          [{'m': 2}, {'k': 2}, 2]
```

And our output should be like below.

```
   a  b          c
0  1  2          1
1  1  2          {'k': 1}
2  1  2          2
3  3  2          {'m': 2}
4  3  2          {'k': 2}
5  3  2          2
```

Sp, as you can in output, each element of list is in row and other column a and b values are repeating corresponding to list element

Comment: This is a dupe. Have you searched for it?

Comment: @AntonvBR what is dupe?

Comment: Can lists have variable size?

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko , we can create new column acc. to size of list in column c

Comment: Something like this: `df.set_index(['a','b'])['c'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index().drop('level_2', 1).rename(columns={0:'c'})`

Comment: @TarunKhaneja A dupe is a common word used for a question that is a duplicate of something. I identified this question as already answered and made a search.

Comment: @AntonvBR Thanks! it worked

Answer (score 1):

The solutions from the questions linked in the comments are outdated. These days you can just:

```py
df.explode('c')
```